# Why blindfold nightwing when the alpha obviously doesn't need to look at a dragon's eyes?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon-2

I watched How to Train your Dragon part 2.

It shows the alpha following the alpha because of it's mind power over them. This is emphasized when NightFury kills Stoick the Vast while under the enemy alpha's power.

At another point, NightFury 'chooses' to fight and become the alpha.

Why make the good and evil alpha the same breed when they doesn't really need to be. I am quite confused.

Answer (score 6):

You are a keen observer.
It's perfectly reasonable to expect that the psychic power of alpha is in effect rather than his(or her) vision.

But a possible explanation (just to explain) is that, maybe alpha needs to have eye contact to set up the control over a dragon and once set, it could guide them on its will until it gets distracted as was the case when it was fighting Toothless. If you observed, none of the dragons attacked Toothless when he(or she) was attacking the alpha, and once Toothless overpowered alpha *(all other dragons fell out of alpha's control and sided with toothless)*, all of them unleashed an all out attack.

Though, I didn't get your question of good alpha and bad alpha being same breed. What do you mean?

Comment: What I mean by good alpha was the one that lives with Valka. The bad alpha seems to be the alpha dragon of Drago Bludvist.